# Populating a circle with dots, using bias towards the edge of the cirlcle

Tags: plot, processing, geometry, p5.js

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image: example of dot circle with bias towards edges]

So far I am happy with the code I have, borrowing from Wolfram and another source for some maths.

But I can't figure out how to integrate some bias calculation, or simply a method to distribute what will be random, but kind of organised!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's my code, which will run in browser using P5

```js
var numDots = 3000;
var dotSize = 1.5;
var dotCoordinates = [];
var randomHue;
var xoff = 0;
var fps = 30;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,600);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
  randomHue = random(360);
  frameRate(fps);

  for(i=0; i < numDots; i++) {
    var rnd = map(noise(xoff),0,1,0,width);
    var R = 300; //circle radius
    var a = random(rnd) * TWO_PI; //random angle

    // var r = R * noise(rnd);      // donuts
    // var r = R * noise(random());   // dust rings
    // var r = R * random(noise(rnd));  // starburst
    var r = R*0.6 * sqrt(random());   // solid

    var x = width/2 + r * cos(a);
    var y = height/2 + r * sin(a);  
    result = createVector(x,y);
    dotCoordinates.push(result);
    xoff += 0.001;
  }    

}

function draw() {
  background(randomHue,100,10);
  noStroke();

  for(i=0; i < dotCoordinates.length; i++) {  
    fill(randomHue,50,80);
    ellipse(dotCoordinates[i]['x'], dotCoordinates[i]['y'], dotSize, dotSize);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you understand how to properly sample points from a circle or sphere, biasing the sampling function to sample it in some other manner should be easy

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure I understand you - I am not sampling from a circle currently, I am distributing arbitrarily across a circle. I can see a way where perhaps I iterate over each point in the dotCoordinates array and any points closer to the edge of the circle are pushed more extremely to the edge. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: No, I mean random sampling. The process of generating a random point in a desired geometry with a desired probability distribution about that geometry. Often used for Monte Carlo simulations.

Comment: @tehhowch I was unaware of the Monte Carlo simulation. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do reminds me of the [Poincare disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model). What you can do is randomly pick a *hyperbolic distance*, `h`, of the point from the center of the disc and then use the conversion `r = tanh(h/2)` to convert it to the Euclidean distance from the center. Proof of concept:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(250, 250);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    let theta = random(0, TWO_PI);
    let h = randomGaussian(3.3); //experiment with different means
    let r = (exp(h) - 1) / (exp(h) + 1);
    let x = width / 2 * r * cos(theta);
    let y = height / 2 * r * sin(theta);
    ellipse(x,y,1,1); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Typical output is illustrated below. You can try different means and standard deviations (other than the default 1) in the call to `randomGaussian()` to tweak the appearance.

[image]